# OpenOffice Relations between tables

Tags: database, openoffice-base

[image]

I'm making a database in OpenOffice, and I was trying to make a relation between tables, but when I make a form and want to test it, it shows me this error.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to insert a value into `teacher`, which represents the relation between a `teacherinf` and `kids`, without first inserting the teacher's details to `teacherinf`. This causes a violation of the foreign key, and the insertion to fail.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the `Teacherinf` record doesn't exist yet when you want to insert your `teacher` record.

You have to create your `Kids` and `Teacherinf`records before creating a `Teacher` otherwise the [constraints](http://plan-b-for-openoffice.org/glossary/term/foreign-key) you defined are violated.